# How to set the zoom level to browser in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, browser, zooming

In my windows phone 8 application, I want to open a page in web browser.
For that I have taken WebBrowser.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="addComBrowser" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" MinWidth="480" MinHeight="796" />
    </Grid>
```

Now in the code behind file I've set the url.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://blablabla.....");
        addComBrowser.Source = uri;
```

Now when I run the app, The content in the browser displaying in very small size. 
Below is the output.

[image]

**How should I increase the font size of how should i increase the zoom level.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the HTML maybe you can add the viewport metadata:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Insert this in between `<head>` and `</head>` in your `html`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```